# How do you increment on parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, increment

I am having trouble incrementing a value on parse.com. Nothing happens and the value remains at 0.

First I set the value to 0 in the postactivity:

```
Counter count = new Counter();
int Counts = 0;
count.setVote(counts);
count.saveInBackground();
```

On my parse.com class I have:

```
public int getVote() {
    return getInt("vote");
}

public void setVote(int value) {
    put("vote",value");
}
```

In the `MainActivity` I have:

```
public View getItemView(final Counter count,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    if(view==null) {
        view = View.inflate(getContent(),R.layout.count_item,null);
    }

    ImageButton vote=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnvoteup);
    vote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count.increment("vote",1);
                count.saveInBackground();
            }
        });
    return view;
}
```

The code used to work before and I am not sure what has changed to cause it to stop working.

Comment: Can you properly format your question?

Comment: How do you test to see if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want to do, but if you want to increment a counter by 1, create a column of type number and do this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassName");

// Retrieve the object by id
query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject myobject, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
      // will get sent to the Parse Cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
     myobject.increment("score");
     myobject.saveInBackground();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my answer if you found it useful